# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tooltip'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-tooltip

I am trying to use the jQuery tooltip, which was working before, however I am getting this uncaught type error in the Console in the following line:

```
$("img[title]").tooltip();
```

code:

```
<title></title>
        <link href="Styles/MainMaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $("img[title]").tooltip();
          });
    </script>
        <link href="Styles/PopUpWindow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

What could have I done wrong?

Comment: What you expect with [title]? can it be [name=title], or id?

Comment: nope, as I said it was working perfectly before..

Comment: You are using 2 JS Libraries, conflict for sure

Comment: you have 3 jquery libraries included in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your scripts conflicting.

You should organise your scripts like:

```
   <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/MainMaster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("img[title]").tooltip();
        });
    </script>
    <link href="Styles/PopUpWindow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```